# AWS SES HTTPS custom domain click link

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

i try to using AWS SES HTTPS custom domain click link for my email. following my configuration:

- Domain, HSTS subdomain preload enable
- Cloudfront, link.mydomain.com as alias for dxxx.cloudfront.net origin [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)
- SES, custom domain link e.link.mydomain.com
- NS1 Dns,

  - link.mydomain.com in CNAME r.us-east-1.awstrack.me
  - e.link.mydomain.com in CNAME dxxx.cloudfront.net
- ACM, request wildcard SSL and using to my CDN.

when test the link i got ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH in browser.

whether SSL by ACM not valid to used for custom domain click link tracking?

appreciate for any help.